# Use a method from another JavaFX class Java

Tags: java, class, javafx, methods

So if you are familiar with JavaFX, `Buttons` objects can be modified with the following `Node` methods

```
myButton.setTranslateX(10);
myButton.setTranslateY(-10);
```

Those methods works inside

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {}
```

For which I understand, `start` is a method in `Application` to run JavaFX purpose. Since all `myButton` objects will have the same structure, i tried to make the following method in `Main.java` file

```
public void createMyButton(double X, double Y, String label, String image_path) throws Exception {
    this.setTranslateX(X);
    this.setTranslateY(Y);
    this.setText(label);
    //TO DO this.setButtonImage(src=image_path);
 }
```

However I understand that the methods inside `createMyButton` are from another class (from `Node` I think). And (of course) i get the error

```
Cannot resolve method 'setTranslateX' in 'Main' s
```

since the compiler is looking those methods in my program, not in JavaFX SDK. How can I call other class methods in my own methods? I tried with

```
public void createMyButton(bla bla) throws Exception extends Node
public void createMyButton(bla bla) throws Exception extends Application
```

but i think Iam completely outside the diamond. I also trying to make my own `class` which inherits methods from other `class` but it's a little bit outside of my current knowledge and i was wondering if there is a easier/*straighter*  way to do it

Comment: Ooooh you right and it gave me an idea that seems to be working, instead of a void method am changing it to return Button method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a JavaFX person but I think the issue is that you're calling `this.setTranslateX(X);` in a method where `this` is not a button (I think it's a Main object perhaps, need to see more code to be sure).

Try this:

```
public Button createMyButton(double X, double Y, String label, String image_path) throws Exception {
    Button button = new Button(...) // not sure how you're initialising your buttons normally
    button.setTranslateX(X);
    button.setTranslateY(Y);
    button.setText(label);
    button.setButtonImage(src=image_path);
    return button
}
```

Then, elsewhere when you want to create a button, you'd call the method instead:

```
Button button = createMyButton(10, 20, "My Button", "images/button.png")
```

Comment: yeap, seem to be working. Changing Void to a Return method instead